# Android List View Custom Adapter with Checkbox multiple selection and Search Listview

Tags: android

I Have implemented the `ListView` with Custom Adopter class and Multiple check box selection . Its working fine . After that I have given search the name in *ListView*. If I checked row item then I search the name in search , Search positioned was changed .  Kindly help me to fix this.

**Model Class**

```
    public class FullUser {
    String name=null;
    String id=null;
    boolean checked;
    public FullUser(String name, String id,boolean checked){
        this.name=name;
        this.id = id;
        this.checked = checked;

    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getChecked(){
        return this.checked;
    }
    public void setChecked(Boolean checked){
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  this.name;

    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
    public class FullUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FullUser> {
    private ArrayList<FullUser> originalList;
    private ArrayList<FullUser> fullUsers;
    private SubjectFilter filter;


    public FullUserAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<FullUser> fullUsers) {
        super(context, resource, fullUsers);
        this.fullUsers = new ArrayList<FullUser>();
        this.fullUsers.addAll(fullUsers);
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<FullUser>();
        this.originalList.addAll(fullUsers);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fullUsers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public FullUser getItem(int position) {
        return fullUsers.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null){
            filter  = new SubjectFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("UserConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        View row;
        if (convertView == null) {
            row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row_with_checkbox, parent, false);
        }else{
            row = convertView;
        }
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name_view = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        holder.firstchar_view = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.first_char);
        holder.groupid = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowid);
        holder.checkBox =(CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

        final FullUser group =getItem(position);
        holder.groupid.setText(group.getId());

        //holder.checkBox.setChecked(checkedHolder[position]);

        String communityname_text = group.getName();
        holder.name_view.setText(group.getName());
        String firstchar = communityname_text.substring(0, 1);
        holder.firstchar_view.setText(firstchar);


         holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked == true)
                group.setChecked(true);
                else
                    group.setChecked(false);

            }
        });


        row.setTag(holder);

        return row;
    }



    private class SubjectFilter extends Filter
    {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
            {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<FullUser> filteredItems = new ArrayList<FullUser>();

                for(int i = 0, l = fullUsers.size(); i < l; i++)
                {
                    FullUser group = fullUsers.get(i);
                    if(group.toString().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        FullUser grouplistss = new FullUser(group.getName(),group.id,group.getChecked());
                        filteredItems.add(grouplistss);

                    }
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            }
            else
            {
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    result.values = originalList;
                    result.count = originalList.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,Filter.FilterResults results) {

            if(results.count > 0) {
                fullUsers = (ArrayList<FullUser>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                clear();
                for(int i = 0, l = fullUsers.size(); i < l; i++)
                    add(fullUsers.get(i));

            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name_view;
        TextView firstchar_view;
        TextView groupid;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by using filterable you can't do this

Comment: Thank you so much  for your reply . Is there any option to do search and select check box .

Comment: `"Search positioned was changed"` what was changed?

Comment: that means, if i choose the first row item, then search any of the row automatically last of row item choosed .

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

          if(isChecked){

             group.setChecked(true);
             int pos = originalList.indexOf(group)
             originalList.get(pos).setChecked(true);
             fullUsers.get(position).setChecked(true);
           }else{

            group.setChecked(false);
            int pos = originalList.indexOf(group)
             originalList.get(pos).setChecked(true);
            fullUsers.get(position).setChecked(false);
           }

        }
```

Comment: While filter time automatically checked position changed to search result row item .

Comment: Is there any other ways to do , like search list view and list view should have option for checkbox  . Thank you so much . please let me know .

Comment: Can u please let me know the other way ? any sample link pls send to me . Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

update your adapter use `SparseBooleanArray`

```
    public class FullUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FullUser> {
    private ArrayList<FullUser> originalList;
    private ArrayList<FullUser> fullUsers;
    private SubjectFilter filter;
    SparseBooleanArray booleanArray ;


    public FullUserAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<FullUser> fullUsers) {
        super(context, resource, fullUsers);
        this.fullUsers = new ArrayList<FullUser>();
        this.fullUsers.addAll(fullUsers);
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<FullUser>();
        this.originalList.addAll(fullUsers);
        booleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        .
        .
        .

        final FullUser group =getItem(position);
        holder.groupid.setText(group.getId());
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(booleanArray.get(group.getId().hashCode(),false));
         holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            booleanArray.put(group.getId().hashCode(), isChecked);
            }
        });
        .
        .
        .
        return row;
    }

   public ArrayList<FullUser> getSelectedItems() {
         ArrayList<FullUser> list  = new ArrayList<>();
         for(FullUser group:fullUsers){
             if(booleanArray.get(group.getId().hashCode(), false)){
                 list.add(group);
             }
         }
         return list;

    };

    }
```

Comment: Hi  ,Still I am struggling to get the selected check box values . May i know how can i extract the selected check box . thank you so much for ur kind reply .

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".dashboard.VoterListActivity">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/reqprogressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/voter_lv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_show_me"
    android:divider="@null"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_show_me"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/n_btn"
    android:text="@string/add_family_numbers"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code

```
public Class  Actvity extends AppCompatActivity {
ProgressBar progressBar;
ListView listView;
VoterDao voterDao;
String Token, Userid, Appid, Deviceid;
MenuItem searchview;
VoterListAdapter adapter;

String pid;
VoterDatum friend;
String value;
CheckBox mCheckBox;
Button btn_show_me;
ArrayList<VoterDatum> friends;
ListView1Adapter adapter1;
VoterDatum Model;
StringBuilder stringBuilder;
String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_voter_list);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.voter_list);
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Token = Util.getStringFromSP(this, "token");
    Userid = Util.getStringFromSP(this, "user_id");
    Appid = Util.getStringFromSP(this, "app_id");
    Deviceid = Util.getStringFromSP(this, "device_id");

    initViews();
    getVoterData();

    btn_show_me.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int i = 0;
            if (friends.size() == i) { //do nothing
            }
            while (friends.size() > i) {
                int count = friends.size();
                Model = friends.get(i);

                if (Model.isChecked()) {
                    Log.i("ListActivity", "here" + friends.get(i).getCitizenId());
                    stringBuilder.append("," + friends.get(i).getCitizenId());
                    name = stringBuilder.toString();
                    String joinedString = Model.getCitizenId().toString();
                    Log.d("ls", "" + name);
                    name = name.substring(1);
                    Log.d("fs", name);
                    sendToServer();

                }


                i++; // rise i
            }


        }
    });
}

private void sendToServer() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(VoterListActivity.this, AddFamilyNuberByVoterList.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("CheckedList", friends);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();


}


private void getVoterData() {
    if (Util.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        SendRequestToServer();
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Snackbar.make(listView, R.string.no_connection, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}

private void SendRequestToServer() {
    try {
        RegistrationApi api = ServiceGenerator.createService(RegistrationApi.class);
        retrofit2.Call<VoterDao> call = api.togetVoters(Userid, Token, Appid, Deviceid);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<VoterDao>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<VoterDao> call, Response<VoterDao> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    voterDao = response.body();
                    if (voterDao.getAddData().getStatus().equals(1)) {
                        searchview.setVisible(true);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        friends = (ArrayList<VoterDatum>) voterDao.getAddData().getData();


                        adapter1 = new ListView1Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_voter, friends);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
                        btn_show_me.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } else {
                        searchview.setVisible(false);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Snackbar.make(listView, R.string.no_data_found, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    searchview.setVisible(false);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Snackbar.make(listView, R.string.no_data_found + response.message(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<VoterDao> call, Throwable t) {
                try {
                    searchview.setVisible(false);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Snackbar.make(listView, "" + t.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("message", "" + t.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("onFAilureExecute" + t.getMessage());
                    if (t != null)
                        t.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Throwable th) {
                    th.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void initViews() {
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.reqprogressbar);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.voter_lv);
    btn_show_me = findViewById(R.id.btn_show_me);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class));

    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class));
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    searchview = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchViewAndroidActionBar = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchview);

    searchViewAndroidActionBar.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter1.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    View closeButton = searchViewAndroidActionBar.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //handle click

            searchViewAndroidActionBar.setIconified(true);
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocalHelper.onAttach(base));
}

private class ListView1Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ListView1Adapter.ViewHolder holder;
    private Context activity;
    private ArrayList<VoterDatum> Friends;
    private ArrayList<VoterDatum> mList;
    private final String TAG = ListViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    boolean[] checkedItems;


    public ListView1Adapter(Context applicationContext, int list_voter, ArrayList<VoterDatum> list) {

        this.activity = applicationContext;
        this.Friends = list;
        this.mList = list;
        Log.i(TAG, "init adapter");
        checkedItems = new boolean[mList.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        holder = null;
        final int pos = position;

        // inflate layout from xml
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_voter, parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ListView1Adapter.ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ListView1Adapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        friend = mList.get(position);
        String nameS = friend.getFirstname() + " " + friend.getLastname();
        String namesS = friend.getVoterId();
        String lname = friend.getLfname() + " " + friend.getLlastname();
        //set Friend data to views
        String Photo = friend.getPhoto();
        if (Photo.isEmpty() || Photo == null) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(activity).load(Photo).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(holder.image);
        }

        holder.name.setText(nameS);
        holder.lanname.setText(lname);
        holder.voterid_tv.setText(namesS);

        holder.check.setChecked(friend.isChecked());
        holder.check.setTag(friend);
        holder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                VoterDatum itemobj = (VoterDatum) cb.getTag();


                if (mList.get(Integer.valueOf(pos)).isChecked()) {
                    cb.setSelected(false);
                    mList.get(Integer.valueOf(pos)).setIsChecked(false);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();


                } else {
                    cb.setSelected(true);
                    mList.get(Integer.valueOf(pos)).setIsChecked(true);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView image;
        private TextView name, lanname, voterid_tv;
        private CheckBox check;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            image = v.findViewById(R.id.profile_iv);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
            lanname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desig_tv);
            voterid_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.voterid_tv);
            check = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkEnable);
        }
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                ArrayList<VoterDatum> filteredResults = null;

                if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                    filteredResults = Friends;
                } else {
                    filteredResults = (ArrayList<VoterDatum>) getFilteredResults(constraint.toString().toLowerCase());
                }


                results.values = filteredResults;

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
                mList = (ArrayList<VoterDatum>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    protected List<VoterDatum> getFilteredResults(String s) {
        ArrayList<VoterDatum> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (VoterDatum item : Friends) {
            String TotalSearch = item.getFirstname() + " " + item.getLastname();
            if (TotalSearch.toLowerCase().contains(s) || item.getVoterId().toLowerCase().contains(s)) {
                results.add(item);
            }

        }
        return results;

    }

    public ArrayList<VoterDatum> getAllData() {
        return mList;
    }
}
}
```

Model Class

```
   public class VoterDatum implements Parcelable {

 @SerializedName("citizen_id")
@Expose
private String citizenId;
private boolean isChecked;
public static final Parcelable.Creator<VoterDatum> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<VoterDatum>() {
    public VoterDatum createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new VoterDatum(in);
    }

    public VoterDatum[] newArray(int size) {
        return new VoterDatum[size];
    }
};


public VoterDatum(Parcel in) {
    this.citizenId = in.readString();

    this.isChecked = in.readByte() != 0;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.citizenId);

    dest.writeByte((byte) (this.isChecked ? 1 : 0));
}

public VoterDatum(String citizenId, boolean gender) {
    this.citizenId = citizenId;
    this.isChecked = false; // not selected when create
}


@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;

@SerializedName("firstname")
@Expose
private String firstname;
@SerializedName("lastname")

public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}


public void setIsChecked(boolean isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getCitizenId() {
    return citizenId;
}

public void setCitizenId(String citizenId) {
    this.citizenId = citizenId;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getLfname() {
    return lfname;
}

public void setLfname(String lfname) {
    this.lfname = lfname;
}

}
```

Get Data From Other Class

```
public class ACtivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
String Mvoterid;
GPSTracker gps;
String Token, Userid, Deviceid, Appid, Language;
Button submit_btn;
ProgressBar progressBar;
AddFamilynumberbyvoterDao addFamilynumberbyvoterDao;
//  ArrayList<VoterDatum> checkedList;
List<VoterDatum> checkedList;
LinearLayout container;
VoterDatum Model;
ListView list_item;
String join;
int position;
String userName;
String name;
StringBuilder stringBuilder;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_family_nuber_by_voter_list);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.add_family_numbers);
    VoterID = getIntent().getStringExtra("voterIDs");
    stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();
     checkedList = new ArrayList<VoterDatum>(); // initializing list
    container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);


    getLocation();

    initViews();
    initListeners();
    getDataFromIntent();
    generateDataToContainerLayout();


}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
private void generateDataToContainerLayout() {

    int i = 0;
    if (checkedList.size() == i) { //do nothing
    }
    while (checkedList.size() > i) {
        int count = checkedList.size();
        Model = checkedList.get(i);

        if (Model.isChecked()) {
            Log.i("ListActivity", "here" + checkedList.get(i).getCitizenId());



            stringBuilder.append(","+checkedList.get(i).getCitizenId());
            name=stringBuilder.toString();



            String joinedString = Model.getCitizenId().toString();
            Log.d("ls", "" + name);
            name=name.substring(1);
            Log.d("fs",name);
        }


        i++; // rise i
    }

}

private void getDataFromIntent() {
    checkedList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("CheckedList");

}
```